# How to select distinct values using multiple columns in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates

How would I select column's, `ColA`, `ColB`, `ColC`, `ColD`, `ColE`, and `ColF`, where `ColA` - `ColC` are unique from `tableA` and order them by `ColB`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Distinct only works on all of the columns in the select clause.
Think about it - if you have 2 record where colA =1 and colC = 2, but different values for colD, how would you choose what value of colD to select and what to leave out?

You can use group by on colA and colC, assuming you can aggregate the values of the other columns (using max, min or ever avg).